# На кнопках не появляются иконки

Tags: java, swing, jframe

У меня две задачи, создать пустое окно и создать кнопки. Окно я смог создать и все работает, но вот со второй задачей никак: иконки на кнопках не появляются.

Подскажите, что делаю не так? Пробовал запускать и через cmd и через IDE. Результат один и тот же.

Вот код:

Окно:

```
import javax.swing.*;
class Window extends JFrame 
    {
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Window gui = new Window();
    }
    public Window()
    {
        super ( "Окно Swing" );
        setSize ( 500 , 200 );
        setDefaultCloseOperation ( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        add ( pnl );
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Кнопки:

```
import javax.swing.*;
class Buttons extends JFrame 
    {
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Buttons gui = new Buttons();
    }
    ImageIcon tick = new ImageIcon("tick.png");
    ImageIcon cross = new ImageIcon("cross.png");
    JButton btn = new JButton("Нажми меня");
    JButton tickBtn = new JButton(tick);
    JButton crossBtn = new JButton("СТОП" , cross);
    public Buttons()
    {
        super ( "Окно Swing" );
        setSize ( 500 , 200 );
        setDefaultCloseOperation ( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        pnl.add(btn);
        pnl.add(tickBtn);
        pnl.add(crossBtn);
        add ( pnl );

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А файлы иконок где лежат? Если путь не указан (а у вас он не указан), то эти файлы должны лежать в корневой папке проекта.

Comment: Честно говоря, я думал, что путь указывать не нужно, иконки сами импортируются из библиотеки Swing. Да и если я не ошибаюсь, в книге ни слова о том, что иконку нужно загружать со сторонних ресурсов. Я пробовал загрузить иконки из интернета и назвать в соответствии с названиями в коде. Все отображалось. Но это не удобно, т.к. придется все время скачивать и редактировать размер и т.п. В самой библиотеке Swing есть какие-либо встроенные иконки? И подскажите пожалуйста, по коду с классом Window у меня все верно? И возможно лучше команда Icon tick = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"); ?

Comment: Артем, в книге в третьем абзаце говорится где должны располагаться файлы иконок. Я люблю сама для себя делать иконки необходимые в фотошопе. Поэтому и не заморачивалась с библиотеками. С классом Window вроде бы все правильно. Только запускать приложение в методе мейн нужно в потоке диспетчеризации событий. Но раз у вас в учебнике об этом не говорится, то значит пока еще не дошли до этого. По поводу последнего вопроса вообще не в курсе. Я сама еще только учусь :)

Comment: Спасибо) Видимо, я не правильно понял автора. В моем понимании слово "создать" стало ассоциироваться с написанием кода, но никак не напрямую с созданием самой картинки :)
Если все верно, то просто загружу иконки с интернета и попробую дальше пройти) Я точно такой же вопрос задал на JavaRush, там мне ответили, что эта устаревшая технология. Но все же, нужно, как мне кажется, завершить изучение книги :)

Comment: Там слово "создать" и обозначает написание кода. Создать объект класса ImageIcon. Но для создания данного объекта необходимо иметь файл изображения. Этот файл можно скачать, или создать самостоятельно. Но в любом случае, его нужно положить в папку с проектом, чтобы программа его увидела. Или разместить в другом месте, но тогда необходимо будет прописать путь к файлу. Поэкспериментируйте. Должно все получиться)

Comment: Большое вам спасибо) Желание работать над изучением книги вернулось, как и вера в себя :)
Буду исправлять код, в фотошопе сделаю свои иконки)) А также советую Вам изучить команды типа  Icon tick = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"); Правда, очень удобно, что все встроено, нужно только где-то отрыть названия иконок)
Еще раз огромное спасибо :)